# Redirecting Pages with PHP causing problems

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I have a page which has a link to a php page which takes data from $_GET and updates a database. After that it returns the user to the homepage with:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/");
```

The thing is that this seems to "interrupt" the mysql part of the code. If I remove this redirect, everything in the database is updated, but when I put it back, nothing gets updated...

This is the database update code, I am using a class of mine as a mysql wrapper:

```
$conn->where('hash',$data1['hash']);
$conn->update(TABLE_ITEMS,$newData1);

$conn->where('hash',$data2['hash']);
$conn->update(TABLE_ITEMS,$newData2);
```

### Notes:

-There is no text or echo()'s on the page and no space before the `<?php` tag

### Order of Code:

1. Data received from `$_SESSION` and `$_GET`
2. Data processed and placed into arrays
3. Data placed into mysql database
4. `header();` used to redirect page

### Code

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
import();

if ( isset ( $_GET['g'] ) && isset ( $_SESSION['itemA'] ) && isset ( $_SESSION['itemB'] ) ) {
$itemA = $_SESSION['gameA'];
$itemB = $_SESSION['gameB'];

$newData1 = processData($itemA);
$newData2 = processData($itemB);

$conn->update(TABLE_ITEMS,$newData1);

$conn->update(TABLE_ITEMS,$newData2);

header('Location: http://localhost/');

} else {
    header('Location: http://localhost/');
}
```

Comment: what specifically would you like to see?

Comment: Sending a header on its own does not stop execution ... the only problem I can think of which may be relevant is that redirecting before closing a session doesn't allow it to be saved ...

Comment: what about the sequence ? since when you're adding the `header(..` part doesn't executes the database statements i suppose the `header(..` line is called before you're trying to update the database , please have a look and let us know .

Comment: i've added the sequence in the question.

Comment: Is it really that hard to post the code?

Comment: @GolezTrol - well I can't exactly paste hundreds of lines of code

Comment: But you can expect others to guess what is wrong with them. Since your program *should* work, referring to the 4 steps in the Order of Code, there is probably a subtle error somewhere that isn't discribed in those 4 steps. I can't speak for others, but I won't be guessing any further on this information only.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I've pasted the code above...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have no idea why this worked, but it turned out that if I change this:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/");
```

to this:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/');
```

everything works. **Weird!!**

Comment: WTF? There is no difference. -1.

Answer (score 1):

If you send a header when previously content is outputted, you will get an error that may cause your script to stop execution. So if the header is above the update, the update may not be executed at all. It depends on your settings whether you see this error or not.

```
<?
echo 'yo';
header('Location: ....'); // <-- error

Update(); // Never gets executed
```

The output doesn't have to be an `echo`. It can even be a single space before the opening `<?`.

Comment: The update is before the header() and there are no echo statements. The problem is that the header() is working but the MYSQL update doesn't go through

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing much of the code, it's hard to be certain, but my guess would be that the PHP page is continuing to work exactly at it was before. What I would suggest might be happening is that the redirected page (ie your home page) is itself doing some database work which is overwriting the changes that had been done by the original page.

As I say, that's quite a wild guess in the absence of any more code (or even any detail about the data in question or what the site does), but I'd say it's worth investigating that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the top of the file. It sometimes helps. You can't output before calling header().
Show more code. It's to less of it to think what is wrong.